# Define given number of tabs in Regex lookbehind (pcregrep)

Tags: regex, grep, regex-lookarounds, pcregrep

I use pcregrep to find patterns over multiple-lines in html code.

I try to match something that looks similar to this:

```
<some-html-stuff>
                    sometext<more-html-stuff>
```

The space between `sometext` and the beginning of the line equals exactly six tabs. Since the expression `\s` matches tabs, linebreaks and whitspaces I thought that

```
pcregrep -M -o -H "(?<=some-html-stuff\>[\s]{7})[A-Za-z0-9]*" /path/file.html
```

would do the job for me. but it does not (I added an additional one for the break). I actually tried this with several variations of the number but neither works.

What did I oversee?

edit:

the match should be `sometext` without any whitespaces before.

Comment: What do you want to match?

Comment: you mean this http://regex101.com/r/vC2yW4/4

Comment: @AvinashRaj see edits above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `\K` instead of lookbehind,

```
pcregrep -M -o -H "<some-html-stuff\>\s*\K[A-Za-z0-9]+" /path/file.html
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vC2yW4/6)

OR

```
pcregrep -M -o -H "some-html-stuff\>\n\t{7}\K[A-Za-z0-9]+" /path/file.html
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lW9eG0/3)

Comment: `\K` ignores the previously matched characters.

Answer (score 1):

This regex will work for you:

```
(?<=some-html-stuff\>\n\s{7})([A-Za-z0-9]+)
```

You need to insert `\n` before using `\s{7}` **to match 7 tabs** OR else use `\s{8}` like this:

```
(?<=some-html-stuff\>)\s{8}([A-Za-z0-9]+)
```

since `\s` also matches `\n`.

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lW9eG0/2)

Comment: almost works. but i don't want the whitespaces not to be part of the string that is returned. thats why they need to be included in the lookbehind...

Comment: You can use: `(?<=some-html-stuff\>\n\s{7})([A-Za-z0-9]+)` for that.

Comment: it does not work. my complete code is `(?<=\"some-htmlstuff\"\>\n\s{6})([A-Za-z0-9\s\.]+)"` with only 6 in the brackts since there are only six tabs... I have tried this solution too but it does not work...does it work for you?

Comment: Did you check the demo link? If it doesn't work for me I don't post an answer here.

Comment: i did. this demo site is awesome! i will have to fix it inside my code but now I know that in theory it works.thanks!

Comment: Yes this is indeed an awesome online regex tester. Glad it worked out for you.